# Time taken to load iAd in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iad, ads, load-time

I have implemented [iAd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAd) in my app.
However, when I start my application it takes around 2 minutes to load the test ad in iPhone once.

After I delete it from the background and start again it takes 10-15 seconds to load the test ad.

How can I reduce the time from 2 minutes to 10-15 seconds for the first time it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have written the Ad displaying code... If it is in controller class move that code to didFinishLaunching. Hide the adView initially and show once your controller class is loaded.

Comment: thanks but i don't know how to do that. can u plz give some code?